# Generate unique file name with timestamp in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, timestamp, filenames

In my .bat file I want to generate a unique name for files/directories based on date-time.

e.g.

```
Build-2009-10-29-10-59-00
```

The problem is that `%TIME%` won't do because it contains characters that are illegal in filename (e.g. *`:`*).

Is there something like [`tr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_(Unix)) in batch files?

Any other ideas how to solve this (that don't require extra command line utilities aside from the batch interpreter)?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

EDIT: A better way of doing this is to take a date/time string that has a defined and unchanging format instead of using the locale-defined ones from `%date%` and `%time%`. You can use the following to get it:

```
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined mydate set mydate=%%x
```

It yields something like `20120730203126.530000+120` and you can use that to construct your file names.

---

(Old answer below)

You can simply replace the offending character with an empty string:

```
echo %time::=%
```

The syntax `%var:str1=str2%` takes the environment variable (or pseudo-variable in case of `%TIME%` and replaces `str1` by `str2`. If nothing follows after the equals sign then `str1` is simply deleted.

In your specific case I think you'd want the following:

```
rem cut off fractional seconds
set t=%time:~0,8%
rem replace colons with dashes
set t=%t::=-%
set FileName=Build-%date%-%t%
```

A more brute-force way in case you don't know whether colons are used (but the order of the time would be the same):

```
set FileName=Build-%date%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%
```

All preceding things, however, assume that you use standard ISO 8601 date format, i. e. 2009-10-29. I'd assume this as simply normal, but some people use other formats so be careful. But since you didn't ask about the date I was assuming you didn't have a problem there.

Comment: %time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2% creates a string with whitespace before 10:00AM!

Comment: As I said, this assumes that you use a sane date/time format for your system. You can use `for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined mydate set mydate=%%x`. The date/time format in `mydate` isn't going to change, it's always `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS...` and you can cut it up to your liking.

Comment: For anybody else that tried to copy/paste the code into the command prompt and got an error, the solution is to change "%%" to "%" in both places. The original code works in a batch file, but not in command line.

Answer (score 20):

Following up on @Joey's and @Kees' answers to make them instantly usable.

On the command line:

```
FOR /f %a IN ('WMIC OS GET LocalDateTime ^| FIND "."') DO SET DTS=%a
SET DateTime=%DTS:~0,4%-%DTS:~4,2%-%DTS:~6,2%_%DTS:~8,2%-%DTS:~10,2%-%DTS:~12,2%
echo %DateTime%
```

In a BAT file:

```
@echo off
REM See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1642677/1143274
FOR /f %%a IN ('WMIC OS GET LocalDateTime ^| FIND "."') DO SET DTS=%%a
SET DateTime=%DTS:~0,4%-%DTS:~4,2%-%DTS:~6,2%_%DTS:~8,2%-%DTS:~10,2%-%DTS:~12,2%
echo %DateTime%
```

Example output:

```
2014-10-21_16-28-52
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this to create a unique file name for the execution of the batch file.

```
REM ****Set up Logging ****
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set mytime=%%a%%b)
set mytime=%mytime: =0%

set Logname="PCCU_%mydate%_%mytime%.log"
Echo.  >>%Logname% 2>>&1
Echo.=================== >>%Logname% 2>>&1
```

I had to add the line

```
set mytime=%mytime: =0%
```

because I had the same problem where a blank was being entered before 10 AM, now I get 09 instead of  9.  I also reuse the %mydate% and %mytime% variable for other files that I create with this script so that they all have the same date time stamp.

Answer (score 2):

This routine, actually only one line, works on every system set to any date or time format.
Output of line 1 is in format 20140725095527.710000+120

The actual date/time format you need is determined in line 2. You can format it however you want.
Just add the resulting DateTime variable to your filename ie. Filename_%DateTime%.log

```
::=======================================================================
::== CREATE UNIQUE DateTime STRING IN FORMAT YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS
::=======================================================================
FOR /f %%a IN ('WMIC OS GET LocalDateTime ^| FIND "."') DO SET DTS=%%a

SET DateTime=%DTS:~0,8%-%DTS:~8,6% | REM OUTPUT = 20140725-095527
```

Answer (score 2):

I made this universal, Will work on any environment where date format may be different.

```
echo off
if not exist "C:\SWLOG\" mkdir C:\SWLOG
cd C:\SWLOG\
cmd /c "powershell get-date -format ^"{yyyyMMdd-HHmmss}^""> result.txt
REM echo %time% > result.txt
type result.txt > result1.txt
set /p filename=<result1.txt
echo %filename%
del C:\SWLOG\result.txt
del C:\SWLOG\result1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the code in the previous example work, I needed to adjust slightly. I presume this is because my PC is using a UK date format. To get back "2014-04-19" in mydate I needed:

```
For /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%b-%%a)
```

Below I've pasted my total script, and included an example of how to use the filename

```
For /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%b-%%a)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set mytime=%%a%%b)
set mytime=%mytime: =0%

set Logname="c:\temp\LogFiles\MyLogFile_%mydate%_%mytime%.log"
Robocopy  \\sourceserver\Music H:\MyBackups\Music /MIR /FFT /Z /XA:H /W:5 /np /fp /dcopy:T /unilog:%Logname% /tee
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**Datetime stamp:**

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
rem set "datestamp=%YY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" 
set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set unique_number=%datestamp%%timestamp%
echo %unique_number%
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can *guarantee* that the machine has a specific version of Python installed on it and accessible in the system's `PATH`, you can use this solution:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`python -c "import datetime; print 
datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat().replace(':', '-')"`) DO (
SET TIMESTAMP=%%F
)
ECHO %TIMESTAMP%
```

This will put the current local [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)(ish) date representation into a `%TIMESTAMP%` variable and echo it out, like so:

```
2017-05-25T14:54:37
```

I've put `replace(':', '-')` after the `isoformat()` so that the resultant string can be used in a filename or directory, since `:` is a forbidden character in the Windows filesystem.