# Rename/update any date string with current date using batch file

Tags: batch-file

So far I have a batch file that renames the file updating the date string in parenthesis.  This works  fine , but the date could be any number.  How do I get the batch to update any date string contained in parentheses.

```
echo on
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set MyDate=%%x
set today=%MyDate:~0,4%-%MyDate:~4,2%-%MyDate:~6,2%


set "_year=%MyDate:~0,4%"
set "_month=%MyDate:~4,2%"
set "_day=%MyDate:~6,2%"

REN C:\Users\xyz125\Documents\Erics's Docs\scripts\"test file (20150112).txt" "test file (%_year%%_month%%_day%).txt"

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `dir/b | Findstr /r "([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])"`

This results in the following file `this (20150609)something.txt` and the folder also contains a file named `test(1234)else.txt` which is not found because the regex is looking for 8 numeric digits not 4.  That pattern would be dir/b | Findstr /r "([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])"`

This post helped [Piped Variable Into FINDSTR w/ Regular Expressions and Escaped Double Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629139/piped-variable-into-findstr-w-regular-expressions-and-escaped-double-quotes) you could do something similar, and set a variable with the string you want the file renamed to.

-Editing to add a note about String Concatenation [see here](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.StringConcatenation)

Also see the answers here [Generate unique file name with timestamp in batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642677/generate-unique-file-name-with-timestamp-in-batch-script)

Comment: Im not familiar with reg express.  Would it look anything close to this: echo ON
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set MyDate=%%x
set today=%MyDate:~0,4%-%MyDate:~4,2%-%MyDate:~6,2%


set "_year=%MyDate:~0,4%"
set "_month=%MyDate:~4,2%"
set "_day=%MyDate:~6,2%"

 C:\Batch | Findstr /r "([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])"

REN "C:\Batch\ | Findstr /r (%_year%%_month%%_day%).txt"

rem ^

pause

Comment: Please edit the question with the code update, trying to make sense out of code in a comment is not fun.

Answer (score 0):

```
@4317867.  Sorry about that.  For some reason I could not edit the code while pasting a response comment. Im not familiar with reg express. Would it look anything close to this: 



echo ON
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set MyDate=%%x
set today=%MyDate:~0,4%-%MyDate:~4,2%-%MyDate:~6,2%


set "_year=%MyDate:~0,4%"
set "_month=%MyDate:~4,2%"
set "_day=%MyDate:~6,2%"

 C:\Batch | Findstr /r "([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])"

REN "C:\Batch\ | Findstr /r (%_year%%_month%%_day%).txt"

rem ^

pause
```